# AWS Lambda timed out error for checking if a port is open on a DNS name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, port

I have a very basic `Python` code that checks if an array of ports are open on a load balancer DNS. So, I am using the conventional `SOCKET` to check it. When I tried executing the code on my local machine, it was running good and giving the expected output. When I tried to deploy the same logic over Lambda, I am getting a timed out error.

My local code:

```
import socket

DNS = ['loadbalancer-dns.elb.amazonaws.com']
PORT = [8099,9087,10041,10004,5001,3001,4001,10010,8085,9050,8088,8081,10041,8086,8072,10025,20026,10006,9098,9099,10005,8070]

for iDNS in DNS:
    for iport in PORT:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        output = sock.connect_ex((iDNS,iport))
        if output == 0:
            print(f'Port {iport} is open on {iDNS}')
        else:
            print(f'Port {iport} is closed on {iDNS}')

sock.close()
```

My Lambda function code:

```
import json
import boto3
import socket


PORT = [8099,9087]
DNS = ['loadbalancer-dns.elb.amazonaws.com']

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    try:
        for iDNS in DNS:
            for iport in PORT:
                sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                output = sock.connect_ex((iDNS,iport))
                if output == 0:
                    print(f'Port {iport} is open on {iDNS}')
                else:
                    print(f'Port {iport} is closed on {iDNS}')
        sock.close()
    except:
        print('Task timed out')
```

My Python version in Lambda is `Python 3.8` and my `Timeout` value is set to 1 minute 30 seconds.

Comment: Is your lambda running inside VPC?

Comment: It isn't running inside the VPC @jellycsc.

Comment: It probably would be helpful to add more logging to the function using timestamps in order to troubleshoot based on what actually happens and how long each step takes in the function.

Comment: Having that said: What are you trying to achieve running a port scan on an ELB?

Comment: Just wanted to see if the respctive applications are running @DennisTraub. Am not familiar on enabling timebased logging unfortunately. Can you provide some pointers?

Comment: Using the `logging` library instead of `print()` is very easy. You just need to add three lines of code. Have a look here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-logging.html#python-logging-lib

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason to the problem. My loadbalancer is an internal load balancer that serves the applications running in Private subnets. There has been a VPN configured to my VPC. So after attaching the VPC to my Lambda function, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout errors can be attributed to several issues.

1. Insufficient processing power. While your code on the first glance isn't very heavy, it still is of O(N<sup>2</sup>) complexity. In case you expand it in future, keep this in mind. This is solved by allocating more memory to the function, which will also allocate more CPU proportionally.
2. Function just needs more time. Can be related to 1st point. You can try using more detailed logging to see where the operation was just before the timeout.
3. Networking problems (most likely). You can use [socket timeout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) to force error on the resource which is unreachable. This can show you that there is some sort of AWS "firewall" block between lambda and the endpoint (security group, NACL etc)